# Allow user to edit destination url of flash banner?

Tags: javascript, flash

I have some flash banners for an affiliate program. On my own sites I use an ad serving program and just set the destination URL of the flash banners using the program. However, I want users to be able to modify the destination URL when they put the banner on their own websites. How can I accomplish this? There's no implementation restriction but I want something as simply as possible for my affiliates to copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you would put the embed/object code inside an anchor. So flash doesn't do the redirecting, they do.

```
<a href="http://example.com/register?aff=YOUR_ID" target="_blank">
    <embed src="http://example.com/banner.swf" width="300" height="300" />
</a>
```

Comment: Says missing plug-in on chrome. Trying to use an object tag doesn't work either because the hyperlink is broken.